# Can we control two independent processes with hardware timers in stm32f

Tags: c++, c, rtos

I am trying to implement firmware for STM32 based micrrocontroller

Two tasks, Task A & Task B both independent of each other. Is it possible to generate interrupts at different time instances so that the firmware switches back to the task once the time is reached
Eg : taskA should run once every 500us, and taskB should run once every 100us. I proposed using hardware timers (TIM) since they are more accurate than operating system's timers. Can you help with that? or maybe do you propose a better idea?

Comment: How long will these tasks run? "Once every x us." is not the same as "Running for x us, then being preempted."

Comment: You tagged the question "RTOS" – are you indeed using a real time operating system on that microcontroller or are you programming it directly (e. g. with HAL or LL generated by STM-Cube)?

Comment: @Aconcagua LL or HAL, maybe better using registers.

Comment: @P__J__ Well, the HAL or LL have the intention to hide these hardware details away from you. Admitted, I don't like the code generated too much, still it is way more convenient than operating on HW directly (using CMSIS, for instance).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [STM32 RTOS timer interrupt and threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63038834/stm32-rtos-timer-interrupt-and-threads)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Edit: This answer assumes not using any RTOS, as not mentioned in question – ignoring the (possibly inappropriately!) set tag. Using RTOS, solution will look differently!*

---

> taskA should run once every 500us, and taskB should run once every 100us

This does not sound like you actually rely on task preemption, rather than if you want to run short tasks periodically. This can be achieved pretty simple, without even needing interrupts:

1. Configure the timer to run in full range (ARR register = 0xffff for 16-bit Counter).
2. Configure the prescaler such that the counter increases each us (with 80Mhz this would be a prescaler of 80, you write one less into PSC register, i. e. 79).
3. Start timer as usual (CEN bit in CR1 register).

Now you simply measure time:

```
uint16_t timestampA = timer->CNT - 500; // so that tasks will be run immediately
uint16_t timestampB = timer->CNT - 100;

for(;;) // main loop
{

    if(timer->CNT - timestampB > 100)
    {
        timestampB = timer->CNT;
        runTaskB();
    }
    if(timer->CNT - timestampA > 500)
    {
        timestampA = timer->CNT;
        runTaskA();
    }
}
```

As in the example task B's frequency is a multiple of task A's one, I checked task B first, so task A will always be started immediately after task B, so there will be no deviations to desired periods (if you do inverse, every 5th start of task B will be delayed by processing time of task A).

In cases where such situations won't be avoidable (consider 200 us and 300 us) you might add an additional timeshift (if you rely on such precision at all):

```
uint16_t timestampA = timer->CNT - 200;
uint16_t timestampB = timer->CNT - (300 - 50);
```

Of course that shift should be longer than the other task needs to be run.

Side note: No need to care for overflows, the unsigned subtraction is robust against, as all calculations are done via modulo 2<sup>16</sup>.

Comment: this is not the way RTOS programming should be done. in RTOSes preemption is bad as the system stops to be "Real Time"

Comment: @P__J__ Where does there any preemption occur??? This solution gets along even without any kind of interrupt – in contrast to yours. How is waiting for an event placed by an interrupt in any way superior to just waiting the required time to elapse? If we are too busy to detect time interval having elapsed, we have some far more serious problem anyway...

Comment: you have no tasks only loop and function calls. If OP is using RTOS then it is worst possible way

Comment: @P__J__ **if** using RTOS. Question description doesn't look like – admitted, there's the tag, though. Placing it might have been inappropriate, so added a comment asking for clarification. My answer assumed not using one.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the interrupt every 100us

Every interrupt give semaphore, task notification or place something in the queue to TASKA

Every fifth interrupt give semaphore, task notification or place something in the queue to TASKB

Then at the end of the interrupt request the context switch.

Another option - use software timers https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Software-Timer-API-Functions.html.

Remember that processes in freeRTOS are not run concurrently - you need to give back control to switch between them (*or enable in the config file round robin scheduling for task with the same priority*).