# STM32 RTOS timer interrupt and threads

Tags: timer, stm32, interrupt, rtos

I am working on a project where I need to execute 2 pieces of code off TIM interrupts. One of them has a slightly higher priority than the other, and both will be running on 2 different timers (of course not at the same time interval). Due to both timers being proportional to another (one is 1KHz, one is 8Khz) both will trigger at the same time.

Since I am already using the RTOS middle-ware for another purposes (threads of a much lower priority than these too), I was thinking of creating one thread of each these routines.

However, looking at how cubeMX is generating code, I am even wondering if this is possible.

I can start/stop these timers from any thread, but there is only one HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback which you usually fill with if statements like so:

if (htim->Instance == TIM2)

Am I correct to assume, regardless of which thread the timers are started from, the TIM callback will always occur "outside" of the RTOS environment?

if so, what would be a better strategy to achieve something close to what I need?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Interrupts will triger. But remember:

1. Its priority (not the RTOS priority as they are unrelated) must be lower the SVC interrupt if you want to use any `...fromISR` RTOS functions
2. They will not happen at the same time (as you have only one core)

Comment: Thanks, so timer callbacks cannot be attached to RTOS threads? if not, what would be a good way to to assign a higher priority to one of the timer callback over the other?

Comment: @zytra - If the two timers trigger the same IRQ (i.e., both events go to the function you cited, you can only process the more important one before the other - or send an event from each timeout event to the queue of a dedicated task, and configure the task priorities as needed. If they trigger different IRQs, another option may be to configure these IRQs at different priority levels.

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on a project where I need to execute 2 pieces of code off
> TIM interrupts. One of them has a slightly higher priority than the
> other, and both will be running on 2 different timers...

What exactly do you mean by "one of them has a [..] higher priority" - the HW timer events will occur just when the timer underflows occur. I think you mean, the handler code servicing the timeout events.

> ... (of course not at the same time interval). Due to both timers being proportional to another (one is 1KHz, one is 8Khz) both will trigger at the same time.

In embedded realtime programming, you should never build on the assumption that IRQ events are not occurring at the same time: Your ISR handlers may be suppressed at the moment when a trigger event occurs. This way, even if two concurrent events trigger closely after each other, it may look for your software code as if they had triggered at the same time. The solution is what your question points at: Context priorities (of tasks (= "threads") and ISRs (= "Interrupt handlers")) let you avoid the question which event came earlier and control which event to treat first.

> Since I am already using the RTOS middle-ware for another purposes (threads of a much lower priority than these too), I was thinking of creating one thread of each these routines.

You are free to deploy code to an RTOS task or to an ISR, but keep in mind that any ISR will have a higher priority than any task. Your TIM event will trigger an ISR (= interrupt context), but you can (and often should) use the ISR to send a notification (or event, or semaphore, or queue message) to a task in order to have the main part of the timer event processed at the lower priority of a task.

> However, looking at how cubeMX is generating code, I am even wondering if this is possible.

CubeMX is not limiting you to use or not use tasks. The question is rather how far CubeMX will generate the code you need, and how much you have to add manually. Please note that you don't have to use the CubeMX feature to generate tasks through its configuration, but this can be done by your own C code, too.

> I can start/stop these timers from any thread, but there is only one HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback which you usually fill with if statements like so:
>
> if (htim->Instance == TIM2)
>
> Am I correct to assume, regardless of which thread the timers are started from, the TIM callback will always occur "outside" of the RTOS environment?

Yes, you are. The question who started the timer is not relevant to the context type/selection triggered by the timer. In any case, the TIM will trigger its ISR (at the interrupt priority configured for that interrupt).

If you use the CubeHAL library, it will implement the root of that ISR, check which of the TIMs related to that ISR have elapsed, and invoke the code you printed. Here, you can insert your user code to the different TIM instances (like `TIM2` in your case).

> if so, what would be a better strategy to achieve something close to what I need?

1. Re-check your favourite textbook on RTOS and microcontrollers. Any SO answer cannot include all the theory to solve the problem properly.
2. Decide whether there will be any more urgent reaction on your system than treating the timeout events. If no, you may implement the timeout reaction in the ISR handler. If yes (or in cases of doubt), implement the ISR with a task notification that goes to a task where you do what the timeout event requires. This may be the task from where you started the timer, or another one.